# Question on the consistency of Zermelo set theory minus specification and extensionality

Tags: set-theory

Let $W=Z^{-}-Specification$ where $Z^{-}=Z-Extensionality$ and Z is Zermelo set theory. What is known about models of $W$ or $W^{+}=W+Extensionality$?

Comment: Does $W$ include foundation?

Comment: As I thought of it yes, but as stated no. Both $W$ and $W+Foundation$ would be of interest here.

Comment: For clarity, the pairing axiom you have in mind is $$\forall x, y \exists z \forall w (w \in z \leftrightarrow w = x \lor w = y)$$ Do you have a particular flavor of infinity in mind? (It might be useful to list the axioms you have in mind since the wording gets subtle without extensionality and specification.)

Comment: I had that pairing axiom in mind. For infinity I thought of closure under the operation $omegation$ which I define as $x\in \Omega(b)\leftrightarrow\forall y(b\in y\wedge\forall z(z\in y\rightarrow z'\in y)\rightarrow x\in y)$ where $z'=\{w:w\in z \vee w=z\}$. But other flavors of infinity might be equal to the task.

Comment: And $z' = z \cup \{z\}$?

Comment: Yes, as I edited before I saw you ask that question.